# Posting to Fan Page goes to wrong spot

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

The following works fine to post to the Facebook FAN Page but only under 'Recent Posts by Others on ...' section. The coding works well if I am posting to the normal FACEBOOK Page, just not the FAN PAGE.

I've tried every post I can find about posting to Fan Pages. Nothing seems to work. My thought was I'm not getting a ACCESS TOKEN for the actual page only the user. OR I'm not getting a return token with the manage_pages permission.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<?php 
$app_id = xxxxxxxxxx; // APP ID
$app_secret = xxxxxxxxxxxx;
$my_url = "http : // www . afakewebsitefordemoonly.com/thispageURL.php";
$fb_id = xxxxxxxxxxx; // ACTUAL FAN PAGE NUMBER


// known valid access token stored in a database
$access_token = MANUAL_ACCESS_TOKEN; // GOT MANUAL ACCESS TOKEN FROM API Explorer - expires in about 90 minutes but good enough to request a new token. THE original TOKEN HAS manage_pages and publish_stream permissions.

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

// If we get a code, it means that we have re-authed the user
//and can get a valid access_token.

if (isset($code)) {

    $token_url="https : // graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
    . "&code=" . $code . "&display=popup";
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];
}


// Attempt to query the graph:
$graph_url = "https : //graph.facebook.com/me?" . "access_token=" . $access_token;
$response = curl_get_file_contents($graph_url);
$decoded_response = json_decode($response);

//Check for errors
if ($decoded_response->error) {
    // check to see if this is an oAuth error:
    if ($decoded_response->error->type== "OAuthException") {
        // Retrieving a valid access token.
        $dialog_url= "https : // www . facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id
        . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
        . "'</script>");
    }
    else {
        echo "other error has happened";
    }
}
else {
    // success
    //echo("success" . $decoded_response->name);
    //echo($access_token);
    /******************************/
    //$data['from'] = $fb_id;
    //$data['picture'] = "http :// www. URL_TO_PHOTO.jpg";
    $data['link'] = "http  :// www .fakewebsitefortesting.com/"; // static link I want to put on post on my site.
    $data['message'] = "Message here.";
    $data['subject'] = 'Some Subject';
    $data['title'] = 'Fancy Title here';
    $data['description'] = "Description is more info here.";
    $data['access_token'] = $access_token;

    $post_url = 'https : // graph.facebook.com/'. $fb_id . '/feed';

    echo "Post URL: ". $post_url . "<br />";
    echo "Data: " . $data . "<br />";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "Return: ". $return . "<br />";
    /******************************/

}

// note this wrapper function exists in order to circumvent PHP’s
//strict obeying of HTTP error codes.  In this case, Facebook
//returns error code 400 which PHP obeys and wipes out
//the response.
function curl_get_file_contents($URL) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    $err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);
    if ($contents) return $contents;
    else return FALSE;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the access token of the page, and so Facebook considers you as a normal user(not the page admin) and adds yours post to 'Recent Posts by Others'.

To post to the page as the page admin use the appropriate access token for the page. You can find all your pages and access token by making an api call to https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me see the obvious and often the problem is right in front of you. I actually wasn't pulling the updated (page) token and was still passing the updated site token. All better now.

Comment: Sadly it says I can't "vote up" till I have 15 reputation. :*( I'd love to, you were fast and awesome.

Comment: I'm also looking for a more efficient way to pull the page token now. I've done several for each loops. Is there a better way to parse and pull the token after   $response = curl_get_file_contents($graph_url);
  $decoded_response = json_decode($response);

Comment: I've tried   $decoded_response = json_decode($response); $new_access_token = $response['data'][0]->access_token; but I only get  Cannot use string offset as an array.

Comment: Thank you all who have helped!

Comment: It should be $new_access_token = $response['data'][0]['access_token'];